# How to override default browser function

Tags: javascript, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to override this function on a global level from a firefox addon?

```
const windowMediator = CC["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
windowMediator.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'start',
  contentScript: 'unsafeWindow.function=yourFunction;'
});
```

PageMod inject js on each page before js on page begin runing(`contentScriptWhen: 'start'`). And than we override window function through XRayWrapper https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Accessing_the_DOM.

Comment: Your answer does not meet the standards of Stack Overflow. Consider explaining what your code does!

Comment: I should include this in my plug-in code? I will test it and let you know if it works!

Comment: For simplicity unsafeWindow = window. So when you do unsafeWindow.open = function(){alert('1')}. You override default window.open